# Como varrer os dados de uma planilha do Excel

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, visual-studio

Tenho um banco de dados Mysql e quero pegar os dados de uma planilha do excel e enviar pra ele.

Já sei como salvar os dados na tabela, só falta saber como varrer a planilha e pegar os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma forma básica de fazer essa leitura de planilhas do Excel (*.xls e *.xlsx) mas, o `provider` deve estar instalado na máquina para funcionar. Nesse exemplo de duas `ConnectionString` uma para `xls` e outra para `xlsx`, dependendo do `provider` pode mudar alguns variaveis dessa `ConnectionString`.

**Planilha Exemplo:**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo para leitura dessa planilha**

```
using System.Data.OleDB;

    //String de Conexao
    string ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\Temp\NamesV1.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    //string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Temp\Names.xlsx;Extended Properties=\""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES""\";


//Código
using (OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = db.CreateCommand())
{
    db.Open();
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader["Id"], reader["Name"]);
            }
        }
    }

    db.Close();
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Read Excel file using OLEDB Data Provider in C# .Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Excel-file-using-OLEDB-Data-Provider-in-C-Net.aspx)
- [Read and Import Excel File into DataSet](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb.htm)
- [How to insert data to Excel file using OLEDB](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm)
- [OLE DB Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: valeu, funcionou de boa sem dar problemas. obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo usar o [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/).

É bem simples de usar e rasoavelmente bem documentado.

Basta baixar o fonte no site oficial e anexar na sua solução - infelizmente não há NuGet package oficial para ele.

Segue o exeplo de como modificar uma planilha já existente:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // SpreadsheetLight works on the idea of a currently selected worksheet.
            // If no worksheet name is provided on opening an existing spreadsheet,
            // the first available worksheet is selected.
            SLDocument sl = new SLDocument("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetOriginal.xlsx", "Sheet2");

            sl.SetCellValue("E6", "Let's party!!!!111!!!1");

            sl.SelectWorksheet("Sheet3");
            sl.SetCellValue("E6", "Before anyone calls the popo!");

            sl.AddWorksheet("DanceFloor");
            sl.SetCellValue("B4", "Who let the dogs out?");
            sl.SetCellValue("B5", "Woof!");

            sl.SaveAs("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetModified.xlsx");

            Console.WriteLine("End of program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

No site deles tem [vários exemplos](http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/) de como realizar várias outras tarefas.

Comment: vou pesquisar sim, valeu. porém, pelo fato do Visual Studio ser da microsoft, pensei que teria códigos próprios sem precisar de programas externos.

Comment: Vc pode sim, mas e um tanto chato gerir. Planilhas, documentos e apresentações hoje são todos no mesmo formato, o [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Então para distinguir cada um - salvo pela extensao do arquivo - é bem chato. Mas todos não passam de arquivos XML compactados. Vc pode criar uma rotina para descompactar o arquivos e depois trabalhar com XmlDocument, mas não será uma experiencia muito agradável.

Comment: usei o código do Virginio (que não precisa de programas externos) e funcionou de boa. mesmo assim, sou grato pelo tempo dedicado

Answer (score 3):

Abra o excel e aperte Alt+F11 par entrar na plataforma para programar em VBA.

Crie uma conexão ODBC para conectar ao banco de dados.

Para fazer o loop. poderá fazer da seguinte forma

Crie um módulo e use o código abaixo

```
Sub CadastraBD()
Dim Planilha As Worksheet
Set Planilha = Plan1 ' Plan1 é a Planilha/Worksheet

'VARRE DA LINHA1 A ULTIMA LINHA
For x = 1 To UltimaLinha(Planilha, 1)
    ColunaA = Range("A" & x)
    ColunaB = Range("B" & x)
    ColunaC = Range("C" & x)
    ColunaD = Range("D" & x)
    ColunaE = Range("E" & x)
Next
End Sub

Public Function UltimaLinha(PLAN As Worksheet, COLUNA As Integer)
    UltimaLinha = PLAN.Cells(65000, COLUNA).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica