# Varrer dados de tabela Excel e salvar no SQL Server (Asp.Net MVC 5 C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um 'input file' que o usuário fará o upload da planilha, preciso verificar se é `.xlsx` ou `.xls` e varrer os dados dessa planilha. Após isso, preciso salvar no `Sql` server esses itens.

Sobre verificar a extensão uso isso:

```
var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".xlsx", ".xls" };

if(allowedExtensions.Contains(ext)){ //codigo }
```

**Agora minha maior duvida esta sendo mesmo em varrer os dados da planilha e manda-los pro banco.**

Tabela que vai receber os dados contém as colunas:

```
- ID
- Registro
- Nome
- Ativo
```

Estou começando com asp.net, pode ser que seja muito simples e perdão por isso.

Comment: Talvez seja até duplicada: [Como varrer os dados de uma planilha do Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175077/como-varrer-os-dados-de-uma-planilha-do-excel)

Comment: Sou bem leigo e não consegui imaginar este artigo no meu problema, onde passo uma string de conexão, mas o usuário que vai fazer upload do arquivo.. Se for algo muito simples, perdão, mas não consigo ver o que preciso fazer...

Comment: perguntando no satckoverflow em ingles, foram mais atenciosos comigo e me deram essa solução: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm
winforms, mas muito facil de adaptar...